# Do we know the Wow! signal was not a forgery?

Tags: seti

The [Wow! signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wow!_signal) was a strong narrowband radio signal observed by the by the [Big Ear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohio_State_University_Radio_Observatory) radio telescope. According to wikipedia,

> it remains the strongest candidate for an alien radio transmission ever detected

As far as I can tell, the signal was printed out on [a piece of paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wow!_signal#/media/File:Wow_signal.jpg), and interpreted by one person, Jerry R. Ehman, who wrote "Wow!" on the printout, in red pen. In [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x67K-Vq1KWk&feature=youtu.be), Ehman claims they had just one megabyte of storage. If the digital data remained stored to be revisited later after being printed, or if it was copied onto external storage, he does not mention that.

I have no reason to doubt dr. Ehman's integrity. But, it seems to me, had he wanted to, with a simple typewriter, he could have added a fake signal to the printout.

Is there evidence to the contrary?

Comment: The link to the paper seems to have rotted so a comment rather than a sourced answer but the wikipedia page suggests that digital data was processed and then printed out and given to Ehman to identify likely candidates for later revisit within that digital data. if this is the case it would be the original tape data that was modified not the paper printout. In the days before computer RAM allowed pattern recognition this style of 'computer lays out data, humans search for patterns' was common.

Comment: Using a simple typewriter to produce a fake reading & output, No! Typewriters of the day did use that font (printing head). If it was faked, which I doubt, the easy way to do it would have been to write a computer program to generate the fake data & then to print it on the printing device used at the time, most likely a line printer. As @GremlinWranger states, Ehman was given wad of folded computer print outs to review. Presumably the data still exists on tapes & if need be can be checked.

Comment: In [this interview](https://youtu.be/x67K-Vq1KWk?t=279), Ehman claims they had just one megabyte of storage. If the digital data remained stored to be revisited later, or was copied onto external storage, he does not say that.

Comment: "...the strongest candidate..." does not mean it is a strong candidate at all, the phrase only says that others are even weaker. Imagine putting monkeys in a cage with typewriters to see how long it takes them to write a novel. After 10 years and a zillion keystrokes, maybe somewhere there is a six letter sequence that could be a word. You can say "This is the longest chapter they have written so far!"

Comment: related in Skeptics SE: [Did we receive a signal from outer space in 1977?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/27717)